# Is it possible to recover files from the TV app library on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, data-synchronization, data-recovery, tv.app

The external hard drive which holds my Music/TV libraries has died.

Most of my library is stuff I can just re-download from iTunes, which is lovely, but some of the files are things I made myself or received from friends, etc. They were not backed up through Time Machine (my library was too huge so I excluded it), nor anywhere else. (Note: they are in my "TV app" library, not my Photo library.)

Luckily, I still have many of those files synced to my iPhone's TV app, where they remain happily playable. Is there a way to download those files back from my iPhone onto my iMac, so I can re-add them to my new library?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using iMazing for that (https://imazing.com), but it's a paid for application, so you may want to hold out for an answer that doesn't cost you.  Is it not possible to sync them back?